# При вызове onclick приложение крашиться

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я использую библиотеку Zxing для распознавания QR кодов и она работает по `android:onClick="scan"`, но если я нажимаю `android:onClick="arch"`:
 - ошибка - приложение остановлено, как и при `android:onClick="test"`

Logcat говорит:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {net.den.appp/net.den.appp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference

Как это поправить?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void arch(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ArchiveActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void test() {
        int q =0;
    }
    public void scan(View view){
        zXingScannerView =new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас не инициализируется переменная `zXingScannerView`, он инициализируется в методе `scan()`, а в методе `arch()` не инициализируется.

Крашится на вызове

```
zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
```

в методе `onPause()`

Вообще это очень плохая практика - декларация слушателя клика в лейауте через `android:onClick`

Comment: а что делать?) я сейчас всё действо с камерой переместил на другое активити, теперь кнопки работают

Comment: Как быстрые костыли - добавьте `if(zXingScannerView!=null) zXingScannerView.stopCamera();` - но это костыли, такие костылиии... :))